# XSLT Similar functionality to SQL "WHERE LIKE"

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following XML

```
        <Answer>
            <Label>FCVCMileage</Label>
            <Value>3258</Value>
            <Iteration>0</Iteration>
            <DataType>NUMBER</DataType>
        </Answer>
```

And need to get the Value underneath the Mileage label. However the 4 letter prefix to Mileage could be any 1 of 8 different prefixes.

I know I could find the value by testing for every combination using xsl:if or xsl:choose but is there a more elegant way that would work similar to the following SQL and also wouldn't need changes to code being made if other prefixes were added.

```
WHERE label LIKE '%Mileage'
```

NB. There will only ever be 1 label element containing the word Mileage

Cheers!

Comment: XSLT doesn't sound like the right XML technology for this. XPATH is more suited for what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I know I could find the value by testing for every combination using xsl:if or xsl:choose but is there a more elegant way that would work similar to the following SQL and also wouldn't need changes to code being made if other prefixes were added.

    WHERE label LIKE '%Mileage'
```

**In XPath 2.0** there is a standard function `ends-with()`

**In XPath 1.0 use**:

```
/*[Label[substring(., string-length(.) - 6) = 'Mileage']]/value
```

**Note**:

```
  contains(Label, 'Mileage')
```

**is not equivalent to the SQL clause above**. For example, it will select this node:

```
<Label>xxx Mileage yyy</Label>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Answer[contains(Label, 'Mileage')]/Value
```

Comment: I didn't realise I could use contains in that context. Cheers!